# Call to a member function getEmailForPasswordReset() on null

Tags: laravel, authentication, null, laravel-5

I do not know why I get this error when I try to reset password.

I have another project with the same code and it works.
I noticed the error is in the "resources/views/auth/emails/password.php" file, that does have a null $user variable.

The strange thing is that in the function the view is called, the $user variable has value.
When the variable is passed to the view, it losts value.

```
public function emailResetLink(CanResetPasswordContract $user, $token, Closure $callback = null)
{
    // We will use the reminder view that was given to the broker to display the
    // password reminder e-mail. We'll pass a "token" variable into the views
    // so that it may be displayed for an user to click for password reset.
    $view = $this->emailView;

    **// HERE THE $user VARIABLE HAS VALUE.**
    **// IN THE $view VIEW THE $user VARIABLE IS NULL**
    return $this->mailer->send($view, compact('token', 'user'), function ($m) use ($user, $token, $callback) {
        $m->to($user->getEmailForPasswordReset());

        if (! is_null($callback)) {
            call_user_func($callback, $m, $user, $token);
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATED**
This is the user model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use EntrustUserTrait; // add this trait to your user model

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Is your user an object? or just a variable? If its just a variable or even an array you cannot call a method on it. dd($user) and show us the output

Comment: Its the correct laravel object

Comment: Added notifiable trait  ``use Notifiable`` inside the user class? what version of laravel is it btw?

Comment: My bad its 5.2 so ignore above,  does your user model use ``use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;`` and extend it? ``class User extends Authenticatable`` Post your user model , its missing a trait  ususally ``canResetPassword``

Comment: I updated the question with the user model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,
the problem was a ViewComposer I had created and forgot.

This is the composer service provider:

```
class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Using class based composers...
        View::composer(
            '*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\UserComposer'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And this is (edited to make it work) the UserComposer class:

```
class UserComposer
{
    /**
     * constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $excludedViews = ['auth.emails.password'];

        if (!in_array($view->getName() , $excludedViews))
        {
            $view->with('user', session('user'));
        }
    }
}
```

With the "excludedViews" variable I can inject "user" variable in all routes except the reset password.